# Get data with not,and

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDB get data with not,and How to get value for INID not equal to 1 and SESSION not equal to 1 ( need to match INID and SESSION in same document ).

Ex:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5946800b962d74070729407a"),
    "INID" : 2,
    "SESSION" : 1,
    "TD" : ISODate("2017-06-18T13:28:43.409Z"),
    "ID" : 2,
    "OUT" : [ 
        {
            "score" : 50,
            "id" : "0",
            "out" : {
                "status" : "unreachable"
            }
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5946800b962d74070729407a"),
    "INID" : 3,
    "SESSION" : 1,
    "TD" : ISODate("2017-06-18T13:28:43.409Z"),
    "ID" : 2,
    "OUT" : [ 
        {
            "score" : 50,
            "id" : "0",
            "out" : {
                "status" : "unreachable"
            }
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5946800b962d74070729407a"),
    "INID" : 1,
    "SESSION" : 1,
    "TD" : ISODate("2017-06-18T13:28:43.409Z"),
    "ID" : 2,
    "OUT" : [ 
        {
            "score" : 50,
            "id" : "0",
            "out" : {
                "status" : "unreachable"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the first two documents.

Comment: @felix Why `$and`? Why are you telling people to write `$and` when they do not need to? **ALL** MongoDB query expressions are "already" AND conditions.

Comment: tried but not getting any results  db.getCollection('OUTPUT').find({$and: [{"INID": {$ne: 1}, "SESSION": {$ne: 1}}]})

Comment: You say you want the first two documents, but in both cases SESSION *is* equal to 1 - so I'd have thought they should be excluded, based on your description of how you want to query?

Comment: I wan to get document that is not having INID and SESSION equal to given value (INID:1,SESSION:1).

Comment: If INID=2 and SESSION=1 then it shout match the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this worked for me:

```
db.yourCollectionName.find(
    { $or : [ { INID : {$gt: 1} }, { SESSION : {$gt: 1} } ] }
)
```

With this query you can have INID larger than 1 or SESSION larger than 1 or both larger than one. Why would you need to negate?

I guess you can also do this:

```
db.yourCollectionName.find(
    { $or : [ { INID : {$ne: 1} }, { SESSION : {$ne: 1} } ] }
)
```

Comment: Thanks lot , it's working: db.yourCollectionName.find(
    { $or : [ { INID : {$ne: 1} }, { SESSION : {$ne: 1} } ] }
)